# ¿Podria alguien observar mi código de java sobre Listas?

Tags: java, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo las siguientes listas: List 1: [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]
y List 2: [4, 6, 8, 10]
generadas en mi main que es el siguiente:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> lst1 = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Integer> lst2 = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0, j = 4; i < 10; i += 3, j += 2) {
        lst1.add(i);
        lst1.add(i + 1);
        lst2.add(j);
    }
```

Necesito crear un método que reciba una List y un índice N y regrese una nueva Lista con cada Nésimo elemento removido. Por ejemplo, List 1: [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10] y luego de aplicar el método regrese [0, 3, 6, 9].

Mi método es el siguiente:

```
    public static <T> LinkedList<T> removeNth(LinkedList<T> lst, int n) {
    LinkedList<T> newLst = new LinkedList<>(); 
        for(int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < lst.size(); j++) {
                if(j < n) {
                    newLst.add(i, lst.get(i));
                    j++;
                }
                else if(j == n) {
                    j = 0;  
                }
                    }
            i++;
        }       
    return newLst;
}
```

Pero al momento de correrlo obtengo la siguiente salida: 
Removing 2nd from lst1: [0, 0, 3, 3, 6, 6, 9, 9]
Los elementos aparecen repetidos. Alguien sabe cómo corregir eso ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T> LinkedList<T> removeNth(LinkedList<T> lst, int index) {

       LinkedList<T> newLst = new LinkedList<>(); 

       //se recorre la lista original iniciando en la posicion index
       //y se hacen saltos de dos posiciones en cada iteración
       for (int i = index; i < lst.size(); i += 2) {

           newLst.add(lst.get(i));

       }


       return newLst;
     }
```

**entrada:** [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]

**salida:** [0, 3, 6, 9]